# how to resolve Following stubbings are unnecessary - Mockito - Android

Tags: java, android, mocking, mockito, stubbing

I am writing a unit test and I get an error message `Following stubbings are unnecessary` - Mockito.

`org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnnecessaryStubbingException: 
Unnecessary stubbings detected in test class: ADataPresenterTest
Clean & maintainable test code requires zero unnecessary code.
Following stubbings are unnecessary`

```
  @Test
    fun `return empty list of quality control checks when offline data quality checks are null`() {
        every(offlineDataStorage.offlineData.qualityChecks).thenReturn(null)// ERROR
        val listOfQCChecks = presenter.getQualityControlCheckData(QualityControlMilestone.FUELLING_ENDED)
        assertEquals(0, listOfQCChecks?.size)
    }

    @Test
    fun `return empty list of quality control checks when offline data quality checks are empty`() {
        val qualityControlChecks: ArrayList<QualityControlCheck> = ArrayList()
        every(offlineDataStorage.offlineData.qualityChecks).thenReturn(qualityControlChecks)//ERROR
        val listOfQCChecks = presenter.getQualityControlCheckData(QualityControlMilestone.FUELLING_ENDED)
        assertEquals(0, listOfQCChecks?.size)
    }
```

Could you please suggest on how to fix this.

Thanks
R

Answer (score 1):

It means there is no need to stubbing this

```
every(offlineDataStorage.offlineData.qualityChecks).thenReturn(qualityControlChecks)
```

remove it and then try. And if it doesn't solves please share `getQualityControlCheckData` and where the mock is used in presenter related to `getQualityControlCheckData`